# Is there a work around for ":" (colon) when downloading from ftp using windows

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm creating a batch script to a get a file based on what option the user chooses. The only problem is, the file in the ftp server has a colon and from what i've researched, windows does not accept `":"` colon.

Is it possible to replace that character before downloading?

Below is a sample of my code.

```
Echo open sample.net>first.dat
Echo user>>first.dat
Echo password>>first.dat
Echo ascii>>first.dat
Echo cd directory>>first.dat
Echo lcd folder>>first.dat
Echo get sample-text-10-16-2017_16:36:00:340033.txt>>first.dat
Echo bye>>first.dat
ftp -v -i -s:first.dat
del first.dat
```

As you can see also, I get a list first of the file names inside the folder for the user to input the file name. I just wrote a specific file name for the example

I'm still not familiar with the for loops in batch but I think that it is one way of replacing the characters in a file name before downloading

Comment: I believe mine is downloading from the ftp server. While uploading, you can already change the character before uploading it to the server. Downloading is different since I cant change the file name anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, they might be different enough in terms of the question. I mostly tagged as duplicate because they are likely going to have the same answer i.e. do something on the system that runs the FTP server to prevent or replace colons in the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Untried]

```
get remotefilename localfilename
```

is apparently valid, so placing a valid windows filename as a second argument should d/l to the file specified.

[Addendum - also untried]

(after Echo lcd folder>>first.dat)

```
echo mls remotefilesrequired awindowlistfilename>>first.dat
rem this should log in and create awindowslistfilename 
rem containing the remote filelist
ftp -v -i -s:first.dat
del second.dat 2>nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (awindowslistfilename) do (
 set "remote=%%a"
 echo get !remote! !remote::=.!>>second.dat
)
endlocal
Echo bye>>second.dat
ftp -v -i -s:second.dat
del first.dat
del second.dat
```

Since I'm not aware of the return format for `mls`, I'm assuming that it's a simple file-list, one to a line.

This code first executes the `ftp` log-on palaver and an `mls` command, creating `awindowslistfile` locally.

It then deletes `second.dat` (the `2>nul` suppresses error messages like `file not found` appearing on stderr)

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `endlocal` bracket a mode where the syntax changes such that `!var!` may be used to access the *run-time* value of a variable, whereas `%var%` *always* refers to the *parse-time* value.

The `for/f` command reads the filename (parenthesised) and assigns each line in turn to the metavariable `%%a`. The `delims=` option ensures that the entire line is assigned, ignoring the normal tokenising procedure.

A series of individual `get` commands is then written to `second.dat`, with the substitution of `:` by `.` in the name.

Finally, add the `bye` and FTP again.

(I'm not sure whether `first.dat` will also require a `bye` and `second.bat` will need to prelimnary commands, but could be...)

Note that it's batch convention to enclose filenames that may contain separators like <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> in "quotes". How FTP will feel about that, if necessary, I can only guess.

Naturally, extra lines within the loop

```
 set "remote=!remote:x=y!"
```

could be used to serially replace character sequences `x` by `y` if there are any other problematic characters encountered.

Comment: Will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you it worked! just need to find a script for replacing characters before executing the get command.

Comment: `set "sourcefile=sample-text-10-16-2017_16:36:00:340033.txt"` then `echo get %sourcefile% %sourcefile::=.%>>first.dat` where the `%sourcefile::=.%` means "replace each character/string between the (first) `:` and the `=` with the string between the `=` and the `%`"

Comment: Can you also do this in mget? the first option is only a single file the second option is multiple files.

Comment: I've not tried - http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm shows the available commands. `glob` is on by default, so `*` and `?` would, I suspect, have their usual windows meanings, but the `%var:x=y%` would only work for `get` which has sourcename and targetname values. Now `mkls` to retrieve a list of values may be usable (but I've no idea of the return format). If the return format is a simple list of the remote names, then ... well, I'll post an addendum...

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll just try to make a for loop since I get a list of files names in a text file.

Comment: I've been able to make it work, but somehow when `echo get !remote! !remote::=.!>>second.dat` runs puts the second value to the next line so when it prints in the text file it does not recognize it as a second value. e.g.`get local.file.date.date.txt --> next line local.file_date_date.txt`

Comment: I suspect the line-termination of the data line, best examined using a hex-editor. Some utilities output a line termination that isn't <CR><LF>. Since it appears that a new line at the end of the `!remote!` string is causing the problem, try outputting `!remote:~0,-1!` in its place. This is a substring selector for character 0 (start of string) to -1 (end-of-string-1) & should therefore kill off the final character.  If a similar manipulation of the other string is required, you would need to assign `%%a` to another variable, then process the end-char-lop and :-replace as individual operations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156964/discussion-between-karl-guevarra-and-magoo).